# jQuery difference in function call $(function(){})

Tags: jquery

I am posting this as I study deeper into both JavaScript and jQuery. The following code

```
$(function () { 
    alert('instance');
});

$(alert('hi'));
```

alerts "hi" and "instance" in that order!  I'm sure there is an understanding into how js thinks on this because I would think it would be "instance" and "hi" - can anyone explain this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(function() { ... })` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Your second is sort of nonsensical and evaluates something like this:

alert 'hi', then create a jquery object of the return value (I believe `undefined`)

Comment: thank you, the fact that $(something) === $(document).ready(something) is what I needed to know

Answer (score 0):

`$(function(){})` is a shortcut for [$(document).ready(function(){})](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) which means the execution of code inside `$(function(){})` will be delayed till the document is completely loaded.

The code execution sequence here will be something like

1. `$(function(){})` gets executed resulting in registering a document ready callback
2. `$(alert('hi'));` gets executed, here `alert('hi')` gets executed resulting in the popup and it returns a undefined value to jQuery which will ignore it.
3. the document ready event is fired resulting the execution of the registered callback ie alert with `instance`

The difference between the code is in the first case you are not immediatly executing the function, you are passing the function as a parameter to jQuery (because there is no `()` after the function definition).
In the second case you are calling `alert('hi')` which will result in calling the `alert` immediately and then passing the returned value of `alert` to jQuery

Comment: I believe the part he's missing is that his second call to $() is being passed the result of an alert.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$(function () { 
    alert('instance');
});
```

, a function is created that will alert "instance", then the function is passed to jQuery (`$`). JQuery remembers the function, and calls the function when the DOM tree is loaded. This is an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

When you do

```
$(alert('hi'));
```

`alert('hi')` is called immediately, and the return value will be passed to jQuery. Chances are "immediately" occurs before "when the DOM tree is loaded".

Everywhere I've tested, `alert` returns `undefined`. Passing `undefined` to jQuery has no observable effect as far as I can tell.